# error when trying to install GLib

Tags: bash, glib

I have been trying to install Glib on my mac. I typed ./configure in the terminal and it configured the source files. However, I was getting an error when trying to "make install".

[image]

any help? thanks

[edit]I am a new Mac User

Comment: The `configure` step failed with an error. Did you try to fix the `configure` error as suggested to you before trying to jump to the install ?

Comment: Do you have `pkg-config` installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually an error during the `./configure` step, not `make install` (or even `make`).

The problem is that glib is looking for [pkg-config](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/pkg-config/), but it doesn't seem to be installed on your computer.

You might want to consider using something like [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [macports](https://www.macports.org/) to install glib.  That should simplify things a bit.

Comment: how do I install glib with Homebrew because I have home-brew. this unix stuff is hard to wrap my head around. my apologies.